# Could Java object.wait be interrupted?

Tags: java, multithreading

In the Java document, it says that the interrupt function could interrupt the `object.wait`. But in my test, in windows it is yes, it could be interrupted, but in Linux it is false, it could NOT interrupted.

It seems that the reason is from the Glibc 2.1.3 the pthread_cond_wait could no longer be interrupted by the system signal.

Am I right for my understand?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Thread t = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Object obj = new Object();
            synchronized(obj) {
                try {
                    obj.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("interrupted");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    t.interrupt();
            System.out.println("interrupt is called");
            try {
        Thread.sleep(100000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds strange. Please show your code.

Comment: the code has been posted.

Answer (score 1):

Java API says that a waiting thread can be interrupted by another thread. What Java API is always true. All JVM implementations must comply what it says.

Answer (score 0):

You should always honor interruptions properly and understand them as a request to terminate gracefully as soon as possible. Whether or not the system can actually do interrupts is irrelevant, as your code could run on many different machines and OSes.

In your code please add a `t.join()` at the end and check if it still isn't interruptible on Linux. Because it might be that the program just terminates too fast before the thread is granted time to actually process the interruption.

Comment: i am sorry that in my test i have the codes like sleeping a very long time to monitor the interruption after the interrupt function called. but the thread is still not interrupted. then i think the interrupt method could not work properly in some blocking call like object.wait().

Comment: This has two tests: one is the program termination and the other is a test for the JVM you use. Because this construct using t.join() happens often, if it is not interruptible, many programs will fail to terminate.

Answer (score -2):

For example this java code:

```
mdInputStream = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( new File( MD_CONFIG_FILE )));
SessionSettings mdSettings = new SessionSettings(mdInputStream);
mdInputStream.close();

LogFactory mdScreenLogFactory = new ScreenLogFactory(true, true, true, true);
LogFactory mdFilelogFactory = new FileLogFactory(mdSettings);

MessageFactory messageFactory = new DefaultMessageFactory();

mdInitiator = new SocketInitiator(mdApplication, mdMessageStoreFactory, mdSettings, mdFilelogFactory, mdScreenLogFactory, messageFactory);
mdInitiator.start();
```